# Redirecting output of a C program to another C program with a bash script under Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have written two simple C programs, program1 prints out a predefined string and program2 takes a string as an argument and writes that string into a file.

What I'm trying to do is to take the output of program1 and pass it to program2. I've been through bash tutorials and the only solution I could find was:

```
program1 | program2
```

This is supposed to work but I get a segmantation fault. So I tried this and it works.

```
program1 | program2 abc
```

As you can guess this results in an output file containing the string "abc". program1 | program2 seems straightforward but I guess I'm missing something here?

Comment: Post your script, you might need to store the output into a variable instead of a straight pipe.

Comment: As he mentioned, his program2 takes the string as an argument, not STDIN. This is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Yes, I modified second program so it takes the string from stdin and my original script works. Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`|` makes the program to the right read (as STDIN) the STDOUT of the program on the left.

But your `program2` does not read STDIN at all. It reads the arguments (which are NOT STDIN).

You should do:

```
program2 `program1`
```

Bash evaluates program1 (when it sees the backquotes), and passes it as an arg to program2.

On my keyboard the backtick (`) is to the left of the "1" key, and above my LEFT TAB key.

EDIT:
If the string output of `program1` contains spaces and you want the entire string to be interpreted as one argument, quote the string with "" or '':

```
program2 "`program1`"
```

Comment: Thanks this one seems to work. I modified the programs so there are two outputs of program1 and program2 takes two arguments. It seems to work with multiple arguments too.

Comment: I think that it's better to quote the backticks with double apostrophes like this: `program2 "\`program1\`"`. Otherwise if the output of program1 contains spaces, it won't be considered as one argument, but as multiple arguments. `echo \`cat aFile\`` is a good example of that.

Comment: Also, I'd mention that `program2 "$(program1 )"` is a valid alternative.

Comment: @lef2: You are right. I will leave out "$(program1)" because it is there in one of the other upvoted answers. But I will mention the " ". Actually, even ' ' is valid, and a stronger escape than " " (although here it won't matter).

Answer (score 2):

I think this should also work:

```
$ program1 | xargs program2
```

Comment: +1. Yes, this will also work. I like backquotes more though as it is built into bash. xargs is a separate program.

Answer (score 1):

You said, “program2 takes a string as an argument.”

The pipe `|` system redefines the program's standard input, not argument.

To take the output of program1 as an argument to program2, use:

```
  program2 $(program1)
```

The `$()` (also the back-tick ` can be used, but there are reasons to avoid this) takes the output of a program and adds it to the current line, then re-evaluates it; so if program1 prints out "foo", the command to be run is `program2 foo`

Comment: Note, if your output will be more than one word, you may want to use quotes.  `program2 "$(program1)"` or something like that.